# Is there a way to group specific CPTs under a single dashboard menu item?

Tags: custom-post-types

My next project may involve dozens of CPTs (it's a ad board and each category would be a CPT, for example CARS and associated special attributes like mileage, gas/petrol and such as custom fields).

By default CPTs are accessed from a menu item in dashboard left sidebar. I don't want left sidebar to be 6 screens tall so is there a simple way to group specific CPTs into a sub-menu under one single sidebar menu item?

Comment: you can do this change in the hook `admin_menu` where you can edit `GLOBALS["menu"]` to rearrange menus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`'show_in_menu'` argument of `register_post_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#show_in_menu) to specify the URL path of the parent menu item. For example, a value of `'edit.php'` will nest the CPT's management pages in the **Posts** menu item, `'edit.php?post_type=page'` will nest them in the **Pages** menu item, and a value of `'users.php'` will nest them in the **Users** menu item.